# why insert is failed&

Tags: c#, sql

Don't get data to IDProduct, but product.IDProvider has number. I try different methods. Help me, please

```
con.Open();
int id;
SqlCommand s = new SqlCommand("select * from Provider where Name = '" + TProvider.Text + "'", con);
SqlDataReader dr1 = s.ExecuteReader();
if (dr1.Read())
{
    id = dr1.GetInt32(0);
    product.IDProvider = id;
    dr1.Close();
    SqlCommand senddata = new SqlCommand("insert into Product (Name, Type, IDProvider, Metal, ColorMetal, GemStone, Weight, Sample, Price, CountProduct, Picture) values (@Name, @Type, @IDProvider, @Metal, @ColorMetal, @GemStone, @Weight, @Sample, @Price, @CountProduct, @Picture)", con);
    senddata.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", product.Name);
    senddata.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", product.Type);
    senddata.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDProvider", product.IDProvider);                  
    senddata.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Metal", product.Metal);
    senddata.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColorMetal", product.Color);
    senddata.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gemstone", product.Gemstone);
    senddata.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Weight", product.Weight);
    senddata.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sample", product.Sample);
    senddata.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", product.Price);
    senddata.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountProduct", product.CountProduct);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    product.img.Save(ms, product.img.RawFormat);
    senddata.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Picture", ms.ToArray());
    senddata.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Side note, use parameters (everywhere) to prevent SQLi attacks and prevent syntax issue's that could arise. Finally use `Add` and specify the data type, length etc. don't use `AddWithValue` as it will infer the data type and may be what you need.

Comment: I don't see `IDProduct` anywhere in your code. Can you explain your problem in more detail?

Comment: IDProduct have automatical insert. In SQL sound as IDENTITY(1,1)

Comment: I could infer that IDProduct is an identity, but I don't understand what "Don't get data to IDProduct," means.

Comment: Sorry, I make mistake. IDProvider. I have correct code, but write "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'IDProduct', table 'JewellyShop.dbo.Product'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."

Comment: The error message contradicts your statement about IDProduct being IDENTITY. Can you show the table definition forJewellyShop.dbo.Product?

Comment: So I found problem. I didn't forget to write in table IDENTITY. Thanks for your help<3

Answer (score 1):

You're using `select *` – there's absolutely no guarantee the zeroth field (`dr1.GetInt32(0)`) is what you want.

Explicitly declare the field you want; assuming it's `ProviderID`:

```
SqlCommand s = new SqlCommand("select ProviderID from Provider where Name = '" + TProvider.Text + "'", con);
```

Then, to avoid SQL injection issues, parametrize that like you already do with the other command:

```
SqlCommand s = new SqlCommand("select ProviderID from Provider where Name = @Name", con);
s.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TProvider.Text);
```

Comment: I tried it. But didn't work, but I have same code from other form this program and other code work